# Black theme ("Night Mapping") doesn't load

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

At work we are using QGIS 3. When we were using QGIS 2 I enjoyed working with the black theme, called Night Mapping, for healthy eyes, etc.
With QGIS 3, when I click on the menu of the themes and pick Night Mapping, nothing happens. Am I the only one ? I want it back.

Comment: I can not switch to a dark one as well. It just simply does not work.

Comment: I think they come back in 3.6, source : https://twitter.com/imhere_asia/status/1094954003933278209

Comment: Try choosing the theme, closig Qgis and open again Qgis. That worked for me

Comment: @GerardoJimenez It doesn't work for my part.

Comment: @Taras I have a suspicion that you're right

Comment: I tested in 2.18 and 3.4....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, download/install the **Load QSS - UI themes** plugin. These contain a selection of themes which you can use including some darkened ones:

[image]

---

*Tested on QGIS 3.4 for Win7 64-bit. The Night Mapping theme also does not load for me but should be fixed in the next major update.*

Comment: the wombat theme is exactly the same that was included in the core later!

Comment: @FranciscoRaga - I hope they asked for your permission seeing as you are the author of this fun plugin :)

Comment: this theme was a Nathan PR to my plugin and later than introduced the idea and this theme in the QGIS core! thanks for your feedback @Joseph

Comment: @Joseph Wonderful, thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @DAAF-Guadeloupe - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: @FranRaga so how can I use the wombat then? I installed the `Load QSS - UI themes` plugin on qGIS 3.6.3 and it works.Can I use it without the plugin?

Comment: @Aradnix If the change to night mapping doesn't work for you, you can't use wonbat theme without the plugin,sorry!Python is needed

Comment: @FranRaga To be honest, I recently started using qGIS, and I just put dark theme to my computer, works well in almost everything, but qGIS didn't change, so I tried to look for information on how to do it and the first thing I found was the plugin, I added it and put the wombat theme, then I saw your comment and I was curious because I don't know how to use it without the plugin as you say, but at no time I had problems with the theme, I clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on Fedora Linux a long time. Since the latest QGIS Version 3.4.4 the 'Night Mapping' theme works. On the other hand I had problems with the 'Load QSS - UI Themes' plugin.
Check your version and try an update. Maybe your problem is also solved.

[image]

Comment: Create a issue if you have problems with this plugin ,https://github.com/All4Gis/Load-QSS/issues , thanks @Michael

Comment: @FranRaga: It's a longer time ago -QGIS 3.0 / 3.2 - where I tried the plugin. I'm not shure, if it's meanwhile gone. Maybe it was just Fedora-related. Gonna try it next days. If there is still a problem I give a reply. Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

It works on my installation of QGIS 3.4.2. I screenshot QGIS with the About screen so you can have some technical info.

[image]