# How to integrate QGIS 3.4 with the DE theme

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, desktop-gis

I just got the upgrade to QGIS 3.4 from the [ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable) PPA. One thing that immediately stands in this version is that it ignores the DE theme, instead yielding an unhealthy white-based theme. In the figure below you can compare it with GEdit, an application that automatically integrates with the DE.

[image]

I have been using QGIS for more than a decade and this is the first version that does not integrate with the DE. I have gone through the *Settings* menus and could not find any option to activate integration with the DE. How can it be done?

**Update**: [as requested by Erik Friesen](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315642/how-to-integrate-qgis-3-4-with-the-de-theme/324181?noredirect=1#comment529138_324181), where is the output of `qt5ct`:

```
$ qt5ct
Configuration path: "/home/user/.config/qt5ct"
Shared QSS paths: ("/home/user/.local/share/qt5ct/qss", "/usr/share/i3/qt5ct/qss", "/usr/local/share/qt5ct/qss", "/usr/share/qt5ct/qss", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop/qt5ct/qss")
Shared color scheme paths: ("/home/user/.local/share/qt5ct/colors", "/usr/share/i3/qt5ct/colors", "/usr/local/share/qt5ct/colors", "/usr/share/qt5ct/colors", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop/qt5ct/colors")
```

And the main settings in `qt-config`:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but can you define what a "DE theme" is for those of us who don't know?

Comment: This seems like a bug, therefore you should make a bug report on the appropriate site. Moreover, the download source you linked to explicitly refers to this as an "unstable release."

Comment: @csk QGis 3.4 is a long term support (LTS) release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully integrated Qt's theme (the one QGIS uses) with GTK's theme on both Ubuntu 18.04 + i3wm and Arch + bspwm (and QGIS versions 3.10 and 3.12). I assume this solution works for most distro + DE/WM combinations on Linux and for most (if not all) versions of QGIS above 3.

---

Here are the steps described for Arch and Ubuntu. Installation on other distros depends on the package manager.

First thing I did was to install `qt5ct`:

```
sudo apt install qt5ct  # Ubuntu
sudo pacman -S qt5ct    # Arch
```

Then, I installed `qt5-style-plugins`:

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins  # Ubuntu
yay -S qt5-styleplugins             # Arch
```

Note that in Arch you need `yay` because `qt5-styleplugins` is in the Arch User Repository (AUR).

For `qt5ct` to work properly, the following environment variable has to be set:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

I just edited the `/etc/environment` file and added that line. Note that logging out is required for changes to this file to be recognized.

Then, in `qt5ct` I just selected the style to match `gtk2`.

[image]

Finally, in QGIS settings new styles were automatically added so I simply selected `gtk2` as well and restarted QGIS for the changes to be applied.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find the OS integration, but changing style is possible in QGIS since 2015 if i'm correct, thanks to Nathan Woodrow

Screenshot from QGIS 2.x below

[image: QGIS 2.x night theme]

https://nathanw.net/2015/08/29/ui-theme-support-now-core-in-qgis/

Screenshot from QGIS 3.X

[image]

In QGIS 3, you can also use the Load QSS - UI Theme extension:

[image: extension screenshot]

there's a dark theme

[image: Example]

Comment: The UI theme [does not function in QGis 3.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312223/black-theme-night-mapping-doesnt-load). Still have to check the plug-in you suggest, however, none of this answers my question.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't answer directly to your question, but tries to solve your problem ("yielding an unhealthy white-based theme. ") What you see is a screenshot from my computer with QGIS 3.4 and the night theme so i would suggest the problem is not homogeneous.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS automatically uses the DE color scheme on both of my machines running Plasma/kwin when `UI Theme` is set to `Default`. This happens because Plasma is built on QT5.

It looks like you're running i3 as your WM (I love that WM!), so you'll probably need to set your QT theme (specifically QT5) to match your DE theme. You can either configure that manually, or set it using one of several tools (or even an environment variable).

When I used to run i3, I set the configs manually (because running i3 just puts you in that mindset). But I have heard good things about Kvantum (mentioned in the second link below).

These ArchWiki entries provide a wealth of information on the subject. You don't need to be running Arch to make use of the info (I run Ubuntu and make *heavy* use of the ArchWiki).

[QT - Appearance](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Appearance)

[Uniform Look for QT and GTK Applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications)

**Edited to conform to answer standards. moved clarification request to comment.**

Comment: I am using i3 on Ubuntu 18.04. Both the QT and GTK themes are configured correctly. QGis 3.4 does not integrate with the DE, be it on i3 or any other DE I have tried it with: Unity, Gnome, Mate.

Comment: Here is QGIS using the custom color scheme from my DE.
QGIS using custom color scheme ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EOPq.jpg ).


Which `style` is selected in your QGIS settings? It's probably `GTK+` or `Fusion`, but it would be good to know for sure. 
Can you post screenshots or gists of your GTK2, GTK3, and QT5 appearance configurations? Contents of `qt5ct` would be *especially* helpful.